# How to calculate time complexity for this algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity

I wrote a function that gets a given number and adds it to its reverse until the number is a palindrome. I'm trying to calculate the time complexity for my code but I simply don't know how to do it or even how to start. Can someone show me how to do this? Also, is this the most efficient way of doing this or is it better to convert the integer to a string?

```
void getPali(int num) {        
    int n = 0;
    int nNum;
    while(true) {
        nNum = num;
        int rNum = 0;            
        while (nNum > 0) {
            int rem = nNum % 10;                
            nNum = nNum / 10;                 
            rNum = rNum * 10 + rem;                
        }
        if(rNum == num) break;
        num += rNum;              
        n++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it obvious that this procedure always terminates? Not to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as a function of the input value num. This code block:

```
while (nNum > 0) {
    int rem = nNum % 10;                
    nNum = nNum / 10;                 
    rNum = rNum * 10 + rem;                
}
```

Will have to execute log(n) times. This is because each pass through this loop will reduce nNum by a factor of 10. So for a number 2^10, it will take 10 iterations of the loop to finish. Also, because nNum is being reset to n at the start of each loop, this loop will take the same amount of time each time it runs.

Then the next part of the loop is

```
if(rNum == num) break;
num += rNum;              
n++;
```

This is essentially the loop condition, but it's written in an odd way. The larger loop will execute until rNum = num. So the question is how fast does rNum increase. The answer is that rNum increases by a factor of 10 each time it goes through the big loop, therefore to get to num, it will once again take lg(n) time.

So the combined time complexity is log(n)^2. Because the outer loop executes log(n) times and the inner loop executes log(n) times. Therefore the time complexity is log(n)^2 (or log^2(n))

Comment: I think the argument about how many times the outer loop executes is based on a misreading of the code.

Comment: This answer has been accepted, but it's wrong.

Comment: Oops, I made a mistake. My analysis assumed that this algorithm will increment num in a way that it will equal rNum. It appears that is not the case.

Answer (score 2):

It's an unsolved problem in mathematics whether there exist [Lychrel numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lychrel_number) in base 10. Lychrel numbers are numbers for which the repeated process of reversing and adding a number to itself fails to produce a palindrome.

Since your code implements this process, there's no way say what the time complexity of your code is.

Of course, this assumes "int" is unbounded and doesn't wrap around like it does in a real java program, but time complexity is meaningless for bounded domains anyway.

The starting point 196 is conjectured to not terminate.